# How to load a bunch of zip folders full of images onto cloud and analyze them in sets?

Tags: python, image, google-cloud-platform, zip

So I'm trying to download this dataset: https://data.broadinstitute.org/bbbc/BBBC006/
and I have a python script that pulls the zip and extracts it locally. It worked on my local machine but each of these is 1GB+ and I don't want to store that locally. When I tried loading the 34 folders on a google cloud with like 50GB memory, it crashed around the 9th folder each time with a memoryerror. 
Had a friend tell me I need to load them into storage first and then pull them in sets into a VM but idk much about cloud infrastructure and could use some pointers.

Specs:
34 folders (from website)
1gb+ each
zip files
on google cloud

Thanks!

Comment: I recommend watching some of the Google Cloud videos on YouTube, They are free and very good. You will then have a better understanding of how to work in the cloud.

Comment: You need to explain what you are doing in a bit more detail.

When you say "loading the 34 folders on a google cloud with like 50GB memory", do you mean onto a Compute Engine VM with 50GB of memory?

Also, where do you want the data to end up after you extract it? On a local disk of a VM? In cloud storage? Someplace else?  It also might be useful to know what you are going to do with the extracted data, as that is likely to affect where you would want to store it.